# No puedo acceder a la web mediante la ip y el puerto (IIS)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

Tengo un problema con la configuración del IIS y no doy con ello. Resulta que tengo configurado un sitio web, y en el apartado Bindings tengo que acceda a la aplicación mediante el puerto **88**.

Sin embargo, si añado la IP `82.xxx.xxx.xx` me accede a la página por defecto del IIS, pero si pongo `82.xxx.xxx.xx:88` , aparece el mensaje en la pagina

> "No se puede acceder a éste sitio. 82.xxx.xxx.xx ha tardado demasiado tiempo en responder."

Necesito poder conectarme de esta forma, porque hay una aplicación que hace uso de dicha aplicación en concreto, y según está montado, debe acceder con el puerto a la aplicación correspondiente.

Ya he abierto el puerto 88 en el Firewall de Windows para que me permita conectarme, e incluso exporté la configuración del antiguo servidor al nuevo, y me es imposible conectarme.

Algunas sugerencia. Os lo agradecería mucho.

Muchas gracias.

Saludos.

[image: Configuración del server]

[image: Tras pulsar en Browse: 88]

Comment: Primero abre el IIS en el servidor, buscar el sitio web que te da problemas y pulsas sobre "Examinar 82.xxx.xxx.xx:88" ¿cuál es el resultado?

Comment: Perdona Roger, es que soy novato con esto del IIS y no sé muy bien a que te refieres- ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias.

Comment: Si abres la cónsola del IIS (también ejecutando `start inetmgr`). Te aparece a la izquierda un árbol con el nombre del servidor y debajo una carpeta de sitios, debajo de la carpeta los sitios web que tienes configurados, puldas sobre el que tienes problemas y a la derecha del todo verás un apartado "Examinar sitio web" y debajo un enlace, púlsalo a ver que te dice

Comment: Roger, he actualizado el post con una captura de pantalla de como tengo configurado el IIS. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Haz un clic en "Browse *:88 (http)", a ver que te dice

Comment: Aparece la página en blanco. Pero en la barra de navegación se carga la URL correctamente y el favicon. Dejo captura.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías subir una captura de la configuración de los sitios y sus enlaces?

De cualquier modo, tienes que agregar como un sitio nuevo, y no es solo agregar el puerto 88 sobre el "Default Web Site".

Le das clic derecho sobre sitios -> Agregar sitio web... -> Colocas el nombre que quieras, apuntas a la carpeta donde esta tu web y marcas el puerto 88 y con eso debería bastar. EJ:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ronpy, acabo de añadir una captura.

Comment: es un proyecto MVC? porque si lo es probablemente no tengas que usar la ruta literal views, con solo colocar localhost:88 no te carga los routes como estan programados?

Comment: ronpy, tiene su propia estructura. No es un proyecto MVC. Lo que me parece raro es que carga al darle al Browse parece que carga la página, pero no muestra nada, es un poco rara la cosa. Muchas gracias.